# How can I show next month and next year in PHP?

Tags: php, date, datetime

I have a request that shows next months and year in two different divs.
like :

```
<li role="presentation">
<a href="#tab1" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Nov <span>2018</span></a>
</li>
<li role="presentation">
<a href="#tab1" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Dec <span>2018</span></a>
</li>
<li role="presentation">
<a href="#tab1" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Jan <span>2019</span></a>
</li>
```

For this, i use actually:

```
$month = date('F');
$year = date("Y");
$nextmonth = date("F", strtotime("+1 months"));
$nextmonth2 = date("F", strtotime("+2 months"));
$nextmonth3 = date("F", strtotime("+3 months"));
```

and i use a call

```
<li role="presentation" class="active">
<a href="#tab1" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"><?php echo $month; ?> 
<span><?php echo $year; ?></span></a>
</li>
<li role="presentation" class="active">
<a href="#tab1" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"><?php echo $nextmonth; ?> 
<span><?php echo $year; ?></span></a>
</li>
<li role="presentation" class="active">
<a href="#tab1" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"><?php echo $nextmonth2; ?> 
<span><?php echo $year; ?></span></a>
</li>
```

etc...

it works when we are in the same year, but i search a trick for show good year if month+ exceeds actual year..
if i call +12 months, i need the good year.

Hope someone have an idea,
thanks a lot!

Comment: What, exactly, is your question?

Comment: make a date with year AND month, make your process with it and when you print it, print only the month or the year of this date. (instead of 2 sparate dates for month and year)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same you actually did for nextmonth, you could also use for nextyear.

```
$nextyear = date("Y", strtotime("+1 months"));
$nextyear2 = date("Y", strtotime("+2 months"));
$nextyear3 = date("Y", strtotime("+3 months"));
```